# How to change a date format?

Tags: javascript, date

I am just doing a question and answer web app. I have a date like `October 10th 2018, 10:04` but rather than display the date as its form i want to change like `today, yesterday, 2 days ago`. Depending on the date it far from the current date?

Comment: If you are using moment, it has a method fromNow()

Comment: Yeah i used moment. Can you show me in a code?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/ . link to moment library